# Сжать массив удалив из него отрицательные элементы. C#

Tags: c#, массивы, пузырьковая-сортировка

Элементы массива задать случайным образом в диапазоне от -10 до 10. Использовать алгоритм сортировки методом пузыря. Есть одномерный массив длиной N = 30. "Сжать" массив, удалив из него все отрицательные элементы. Отсортировав первую половину нового массива за убыванием. C#

Заготовка:

```
    int[] arr = new int[30];
    int i, j;

    Random rand = new Random();

    for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand.Next(-10, 10);
        Console.Write("  " + arr[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
```

- 

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: Нужно рассчитать количество элементов в сжатом массиве) Под переменной N

Comment: Ну, после сортировки, отрицательные элементы у вас в начале массива. Находите индекс первого неотрицательного. И от него и до конца массива - количество элементов в новом массиве, создаете его и копируете элементы в цикле.

Comment: Мне бы код :)))

Comment: Я слишком ленив сегодня для написания таких простых штук алгоритмически. А решение с использованием встроенных средств дотнета вам не подойдет, типа для отсортированного массива `int[] newArray = arr.SkipWhile(x => x < 0).ToArray();` Но суть я вам расписал, учитесь писать код самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибооо))))))